# Behavior of np.c_ with list and tuple arguments

Tags: python, numpy

The output of `np.c_` differs when its arguments are lists or tuples. Consider the output of the three following lines

```
np.c_[[1,2]]
np.c_[(1,2)]
np.c_[(1,2),]
```

With a list argument, `np.c_` returns a column array, as expected. When the argument is a tuple instead (second line), it returns a 2D row. Adding a comma after the tuple (third line) returns a column array as for the first call.

Can somebody explain the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: Look at the code.  This and other classes/functions in file (`indexing_tricks`?) is a convenience, but interesting coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 common use cases for `np.c_`:

- `np.c_` can accept a sequence of 1D array-likes:

  ```
  In [98]: np.c_[[1,2],[3,4]]
  Out[98]: 
  array([[1, 3],
         [2, 4]])
  ```
- or, `np.c_` can accept a sequence of 2D array-likes:

  ```
  In [96]: np.c_[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]
  Out[96]: 
  array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
         [3, 4, 7, 8]])
  ```

So `np.c_` can be passed 1D array-likes or 2D array-likes. 
But that raises the question how is `np.c_` supposed to recognize if the input is a single 2D array-like (e.g. [[1,2],[3,4]]) or a sequence of 1D array-likes (e.g. [1,2], [3,4])?

The developers made a design decision: If `np.c_` is passed a tuple, the argument will be treated as a sequence of separate array-likes. If it is passed a non-tuple (such as a list), then that object will be consider a single array-like.

Thus, `np.c_[[1,2], [3,4]]` (which is equivalent to `np.c_[([1,2], [3,4])]`) will treat `([1,2], [3,4])` as two separate 1D arrays.

```
In [99]: np.c_[[1,2], [3,4]]
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

In contrast, `np.c_[[[1,2], [3,4]]]` will treat `[[1,2], [3,4]]` as a single 2D array.

```
In [100]: np.c_[[[1,2], [3,4]]]
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

---

So, for the examples you posted:

`np.c_[[1,2]]` treats `[1,2]` as a single 1D array-like, so it makes [1,2] into a column of a 2D array:

```
In [101]: np.c_[[1,2]]
Out[101]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

`np.c_[(1,2)]` treats `(1,2)` as 2 separate array-likes, so it places each value into its own column:

```
In [102]: np.c_[(1,2)]
Out[102]: array([[1, 2]])
```

`np.c_[(1,2),]` treats the tuple `(1,2),` (which is equivalent to `((1,2),)`) as a sequence of one array-like, so that array-like is treated as a column:

```
In [103]: np.c_[(1,2),]
Out[103]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

---

PS. Perhaps more than most packages, NumPy has a history of [treating lists and tuples differently](http://web.archive.org/web/20130617020606/http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-September/058390.html). That link discusses how lists and tuples are treated differenty when passed to `np.array`.

Answer (score 2):

The first level on handling the argument comes from the Python interpreter, which translates a [...] into a call to `__getitem__`:

```
In [442]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __getitem__(self,args):
     ...:         print(args)
     ...:        
In [443]: Foo()['str']
str
In [444]: Foo()[[1,2]]
[1, 2]
In [445]: Foo()[[1,2],]
([1, 2],)
In [446]: Foo()[(1,2)]
(1, 2)
In [447]: Foo()[(1,2),]
((1, 2),)
```

`np.c_` is an instance of `np.lib.index_tricks.AxisConcatenator`.  It's `__getitem__`

```
    # handle matrix builder syntax
    if isinstance(key, str):
        ....
        mymat = matrixlib.bmat(...)
        return mymat

    if not isinstance(key, tuple):
        key = (key,)

     ....
    for k, item in enumerate(key):
        ....
```

So except for the `np.bmat` compatible string, it turns all inputs into a tuple, and then iterates over the elements.

Any of the variations containing `[1,2]` is the same as `([1,2],)`, a single element tuple.  `(1,2)` is two elements that will be concatenated.  So is `([1,2],[3,4])`.

Note that `numpy` indexing also distinguishes between lists and tuples (though with a few inconsistencies).

```
In [455]: x=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [456]: x[0,1]               # tuple - index for each dim
Out[456]: array([4, 5, 6, 7])
In [457]: x[(0,1)]             # same tuple
Out[457]: array([4, 5, 6, 7])
In [458]: x[[0,1]]             # list - index for one dim
Out[458]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [459]: x[([0,1],)]          # same
     ....
```